# SelectedIndexChanged event fires when the displaymember value is changed

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, selectedindexchanged, databound

My listbox control is Firing the SelectedIndexChange event when only the bound field DisplayMember is changed. I would expect the SelectedItem Changed event to fire, but this thing is firing the IndexChanged , is it "rebinding" because the bound field is changing and therefore causing the Index to be reset ?

`DisplayMember = "MyField";
ValueMember = "MyID";
Datasource = MyBindingSource;`

The selectedIndexEvent does fire when the selection changes too, it just should not fire when the DisplayMember changes.

Comment: check all events that have your listbox on the designer.cs and codebehind, and verify the DisplayMember and ValueMember its right and said me if you found the error

Comment: Henrique - thanks for replying, the designer has the events , I added textchanged and value changed events to see if I could work around this.
Designer Code is in next comment (too many characters for this comment).

Comment: `this.lstBRAND.CausesValidation = false; this.lstBRAND.DataSource = this.bsBrand; this.lstBRAND.DisplayMember = "BrandName"; 
this.lstBRAND.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 95); this.lstBRAND.Name = "lstBRAND";this.lstBRAND.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(171, 264); this.lstBRAND.ValueMember = "BrandID"; this.lstBRAND.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.LstBRAND_SelectedIndexChanged);
this.lstBRAND.SelectedValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.LstBRAND_SelectedValueChanged);
this.lstBRAND.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.LstBRAND_TextChanged);`